# Angular filter issue

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app using filters. My json file looks like this:

```
[{DegreeCategoryID:"1",DegreeCategory:"Accounting",DegreeCategoryType:"Applied Sciences"},
{DegreeCategoryID:"2",DegreeCategory:"Advanced Manufacturing/Mechatronics Technology",DegreeCategoryType:"Applied Sciences"},
{DegreeCategoryID:"3",DegreeCategory:"Air Conditioning and Refrigeration Technology",DegreeCategoryType:"Applied Sciences"},
{DegreeCategoryID:"4",DegreeCategory:"Auto Body Technology",DegreeCategoryType:"Applied Sciences"},
{DegreeCategoryID:"77",DegreeCategory:"Associate in Arts",DegreeCategoryType:"Academic"},
{DegreeCategoryID:"78",DegreeCategory:"Associate in Sciences",DegreeCategoryType:"Academic"},
{DegreeCategoryID:"79",DegreeCategory:"Associate of Arts in Teaching",DegreeCategoryType:"Academic"},
{DegreeCategoryID:"80",DegreeCategory:"Emphasis",DegreeCategoryType:"Academic"},
{DegreeCategoryID:"81",DegreeCategory:"Field of Study",DegreeCategoryType:"Academic"}]
```

I am using a statement which uses a filter like this:

```
<a href='#' ng-repeat="degree in degrees | filter:search:Academic" class="list-group-item">
                          <li ng-click="showCourseDescription(p.subchildren)" >{{degree.DegreeCategory}}</li>
                        </a>
```

But the filtering does not happen.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: i am trying to filter all the DegreeCategory's by filtering DegreeCategoryType as 'Academic'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ngRepeat` expression should look like this:

```
ng-repeat="degree in degrees | filter:{DegreeCategoryType:'Academic'}"
```

---

**UPDATE:**

If you want to use a search-field to specifiy the search value:

```
<input type="search" ng-model="search" />
...
<li ng-repeat="degree in degrees | filter:{DegreeCategoryType:search}">
```

Finally, keep in mind, you can specify a third parameter, indicating if you want a substring match or an exact match of the value:

```
<input type="search" ng-model="search" />
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="exactMatch" />
...
<li ng-repeat="degree in degrees | filter:{DegreeCategoryType:search}:exactMatch">
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/7E3xt/)**.